# function that outputs a data frame in R

Tags: r

I have an example data frame named `df`:

```
    Store    Cash Only 
1    "A"      Y
2    "B"      N
3    "C"      N
4    "D"      Y
```

I would like to create a function that allows a user to see whether or not a store is "cash only". Ideally, the function would output only the stores that have a `Y`in the `Cash Only` column.  The output should look like this:

```
  Store    Cash Only 
1    "A"      Y
2    "D"      Y
```

Does anyone know how I would go about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need to write a function that returns a subset of the input dataframe where `cash == "Y"`:

```
df = data.frame(store=c("a","b","c","d"), cash=c("Y","N","N","Y"))

cash_only <- function(df){
  return(subset(df, cash == "Y"))
}

new_df <- cash_only(df)
```

Comment: While this works (+1, though one could quibble about using `subset` as opposed to `[`) the shortness of the function definition suggests that little is to be gained by bothering to write such a function. Sounds like OP just didn't realize how easy subsetting can be.

Comment: @JohnColeman - I think this is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). OP is not telling us the real problem, `X`, only how to do `Y` (OP's solution to problem `X`) since as you note, subsetting is very simple operation.

Comment: yeah I agree, I just assumed that maybe this is a more complicated problem in reality than presented in the original question so gave them the benefit of the doubt. You're right though, a function is not really needed for something this simple

Comment: yeahp, just an XY problem :) Thanks all!

Answer (score 2):

This function gives you more flexibility,

> select_sub_dataframe<-function(df,colname,value){
>         return(df[df[,colname]==value,])
>   }

You can call this function and get the subset by

> select_sub_dataframe(df,"Cash Only","Y")